# twice insert into the same table

Tags: insert

select * into tableA from dataA.
I have created a table tableA.

Next time,
insert * into tableA from dataB. it doesn't work. Because tableA is already exist.

I need insert data twice instead of unioning dataA and dataB.

Comment: If we were able to `INSERT INTO tgt SELECT * FROM src`  into an already existing table (with same schema/columns), that would avoid a lot of typing every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

select * into tableA from dataA.
Next,
INSERT INTO tableA(colum1,colum2)<--Not *
SELECT (colum1,colum2)
FROM B